# Enable Java in Chrome and Firefox to test self-signed applets

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, plugins, applet

I am trying to create a self-signed applet. I followed the steps of [this](http://www.jade-cheng.com/uh/ta/signed-applet-tutorial/) very straightforward tutorial, but it won't work. First I thought that there was something wrong with the applet, but then I figured out that it is more like a Java issue. After running [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) test, it turns out that I don't have Java enabled in my browsers (or I don't have it installed, but I know that I have it installed,so that's not the issue...).

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I tested Chrome, Firefox, and even Internet Explorer. My Java version is: 1.8.0_45.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

In the Java Control Panel I have Java content enabled in the browser.

[image: Java Control Panel settings]

I have read several posts suggesting that I should enable the Java plugin in my browsers, but it is not even on the plugin list. I also enabled the NPAPI plugin, as suggested [here](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml), but no luck so far.

What am I missing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After java(jre) 7 we can't run unsigned and self signed jar file due to security reason java block that.
You need to sign applet jar file from trusted certificate(no other solution). you require to pay for that following on link for purchasing certificate 
https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/java-code-signing-guide.htm

you also require to update mainfeast file before signing jar from trusted certificate.

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: What I still don't understand that on [this page](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) I get the result that _Java is disabled or not installed_. This shouldn't be the issue of signed or not signed applets. I have Java installed and I have it enabled in the Java Control Panel, yet it doesn't seem to work with the browsers. @Aniket

Comment: which browser you are using?
I told you After java(jre) 7 we can't run unsigned and self signed jar file due to security reason java block that.

Comment: Yes, that was clear, but the page I linked is the official oracle site, where there is a Java detection app that would ask for permission to run, but it won't load. I don't think that it would be the matter of signed or unsigned applets, as on other computers it works, but in my case I get _Java is disabled or not installed_. I use both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is for older JRE.

[Self-signed certificates for a known community](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a)